# Is $\frac{p(x) - p(y)}{x-y}$ always irreducible?

Tags: irreducible-polynomials

Let $p$ be an integer polynomial.
Is $\frac{p(x) - p(y)}{x-y}$ always irreducible over the integers ?

Comment: What does this mean? E.g. for $p(x)\equiv 1$ or $p(x)=x$ you say $0$ or $1$ is *irreducible over the integers*!?

Comment: Nonconstant polynomials

Comment: $p(x)=x$ is non-constant! PS: I did not down-vote, I just want to know what you mean. E.g. do you see the expression as a  polynomial in x and y?

Comment: Have you tried anything? Even barring the obvious counterexample $p(x) = x$ there are others in very low degrees... Do you know the definition of irreducible at least?

Answer (score 3):

Irreducibility is, in general, irreducibility over a field, but anyway, if we take $p(x)=x^4+x^2$ we have:
$$ \frac{p(x)-p(y)}{x-y} = (x+y)\cdot(x^2+y^2+1).$$